# how to track pending HTTP requests in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-http

i want an alternate to angular 1 $http.pendingRequest in Angular 2 or any thing to track globally like interceptors. Mainly for showing a loading icon while calls are been made

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just maintain the state of the icon while the observable has not returned.

Example:

```
export class MyClass {
    private isLoaded = false;

    constructor(private myService: MyService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.myService.myServiceCall().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.isLoaded = true;
        });
    }

}
```

Then use `*ngIf` on the dialog.  You can also consider using the async pipe that Angular provides for scenarios like this:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html

Comment: how do you capture the percent of it being loaded?

Comment: The server would have to send back meaningful information about the status of the request.  Or, if you knew enough about the request and it was being streamed, that could allow you to calculate a meaningful percentage.  Most UI libraries will just "guess" and increment a loading bar slowly just to give the user feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
 getItem(itemID:string){
    if(this.pendingRequest){
        this.pendingRequest.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.pendingRequest = this.http.get(`./country-info/${itemID}`).map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.item = res.item);
}
```